# Apex call from LWC, data looping

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am quite new to APex and LWC and I am not sure how to format my code
I would like to trigger an apex class from a loop
if it was another LWC I would do  but since it is from the same component I am not sure how to do it.

So I am looping through the status of one of my objects in the following way:

```
<div class="card_wrapper"> 
            <template for:each={pickVals} for:item="item">
                <div class="stageContainer" key={item} style={calcWidth}>
                {item}
                </div>
            </template>
</div>
```

now instead of item I would like there to trigger an apex class that count the number of object with that Status:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static list<AggregateResult> PropCountStatus(string CountryId, string Status){
        return [SELECT count (Name)
                FROM Lead 
                WHERE Market__c = :CountryId 
                AND Status = :Status ];
    }
```

How in my HTML can I trigger the current item in my apex class and return the value from my APEX class

Thx you very much

Answer (score 2):

It would be more efficient to do all of the values at once:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static list<AggregateResult> PropCountStatus(string CountryId){
    return [SELECT Market__c market, count(Id) sum
            FROM Lead 
            WHERE Market__c = :CountryId
            GROUP BY Market__c];
}
```

---

```
<div class="stageContainer" key={item.market} style={calcWidth}>
    {item.sum}
</div>
```

---

But, if you wanted to not modify the Apex, you'd end up calling the server many times:

```
const marketByStatus = await Promise.all(statuses.map(status => PropCountStatus({ CountryId: countryId, Status: status}));
```

Either way, there's no real way to call Apex in a loop *in the template*, you need to call Apex in a loop in your JavaScript.